# How to change down-arrow on select tag

Tags: html, css

How to change down-arrow on select tag? Example:

How it looks now:

[image]

How I want it to be:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It isn't, not straight out of the box, at least. You'll need to either use javascript to change the element to something you can style consistently across browsers, or use a replacement-element for the button itself.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try this with pure css , first you need to remove the default behavior of the `select` tag with `appearance:none` property.

*browser specified*

- appearance:none;
- -webkit-appearance:none; `/* chrome and safari */`
- -moz-appearance:none; `/* Mozilla */`
- -ms-appearance:none; `/* Internet explorer */`

  then you can set `background-image`

```css
select {
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 appearance:none;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 -moz-appearance:none;
 -ms-appearance:none;
 border:2px solid #000;
 background:url('http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/small-down-arrow-icon-15593.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:16px 17px;
 background-position:right 0px;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, that seems to do what I wanted.
Thanks a lot, I will mark this as helpful. :D

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple approach with SVG, without an external image:

```css
select { -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; padding-right: 24px; 
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>') 100% 50% no-repeat #fff; } /* change or remove #fff color if not needed */
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I changed ```padding-right: 24px``` to ```background-position-x: 99%```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to leave the choice to the browser how show a list.
Why force the user to change his habits ?

Else
[How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)